# How to make immediate transition without restarting state?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently while proceeding from state A to B in animator, unity restarts state A to the beginning instead of immediately moving from A's end to B's start. How do I fix that?

The transition does not require condition and is not looping.

If I uncheck: has exit time, the whole animation stops at A's end. What is required to make the transition in that moment? If I check it again it restarts A before transition to B.

How do I resolve this?

[image: Animator screenshot]

"move" has keyframes only for position, "rotate" only for rotation and "wait" has no keyframes, only empty timeline.

My Unity version is: 2018.2.18f1 Personal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to uncheck "Write defaults" in states in animator. This way animation clips affect only animated values.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "Transition Duration" to 0, try it with exit time and without[image]

Comment: Still restarts with 'has exit time' checked or halts otherwise. Exit time: 1, duration and offset: 0.

Comment: Can you upload screenshot of your transition settings and animator view? I tried setting transition duration to 0 and exit time to 0 and 1, both ways are working for me. Also what version of Unity are you using?